# Is there something like -mcpu= but for OS selection in both gcc and clang? Or a "choose the nearest target that best matches"?

Tags: gcc, clang

Simple question: I know `-mcpu=xxx` can be used to choose a target CPU on both gcc and clang. Is there an equivalent option but for target OS? Something like `-mos=linux` or `-mos=freebsd`?

Alternatively, is there a way I can specify an incomplete target triplet (say, `x86_64-*-freebsd*` or `i686*linux*`) and gcc/clang will autocomplete?

I ask this because FreeBSD and OpenBSD seem to use version-specific and package manager-specific (!) target triplets.

Thanks.

**EDIT/UPDATE** I've figured most of what I need out, the only thing I'm missing is: is there a way to specify the target to use on the gcc command line, like the `-target` switch to clang? for example: `gcc -someoptionhere i686-linux`? Or a way to know if I should be using the multilib target instead of a target triplet? :S Thanks...

Comment: No. OS is a part of the "target" for which gcc is built (i.e. `i486-linux-gnu`). If you need a different target, you need a different build of gcc.

Comment: Right, now I understand that `gcc` by itself isn't actually a generic frontend. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All right, figured this out on my own (references at bottom).

`-m` is actually for specifying a target for multilib compilers.

For clang, a target triplet can be specified with the `-target` option. Any part of the triplet can be omitted; appropriate defaults will be chosen instead. So all I really need to say is `[arch]-[OS]` or `[arch]-[OS]-[ABI]`. Version numbers aren't important, see include/llvm/ADT/Triple.h in the LLVM source.

Unfortunately, contrary to what I originally believed, gcc does *not* work like this: each individual build of gcc is tied to a given target triple, and the unqualified `gcc` is usually hardlinked to a given target triple. That means I can't use any shortcuts like I can with clang; specifying the target triple is required.

So now I'm going to need to figure out what to do about supporting cross-compilation using gcc and clang with the same tool/build script (not configure, cmake, or scons). Thanks!

References:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html
- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Target-Options.html
- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Target-Options.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4455746/3408572
- http://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html
- http://wiki.osdev.org/Target_Triplet
- redi in irc.freenode.net/#gcc
- jroelofs in irc.oftc.net/#llvm