# How to generate the assembly output which has arm instruction set

Tags: c, gcc, x86, arm

i have a windows machine(intel processor) and gcc installed.
gcc -save-temps "filename.c" 
generated the intermediate files and i viewed the assembly file (.s file)
which is intel x86 instructions.

my question is how to generate the assembly which is ARM instruction set architecture equivalent on the same machine?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.2/gcc/Target-Options.html ?

Comment: you're looking for a [cross compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455705/general-questions-about-gcc-and-cross-compiling)

Comment: You can generate assembly code for several CPU arch on  https://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: thanks, it was helpful... and i also came across "http://gnutoolchains.com/arm-elf/"

Answer (score 0):

gcc is always built for a single target. https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain is where you get your arm-gcc cross-compiler toolchain. Clang on the other hand can generate code for multiple targets.

Both are available on [https://www.godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/gOf5jM) to see the assembly directly.